# Searching relationship collection for attribute value in Eloquent Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

This should be simple but for some reason I am unable to get the expected response. I have a model (`App\Product`) that has many permissions (`App\ProductPermission`) and my objective is to check if a product holds a particular permission described by a text string. I can access these fine like..

```
\App\Product::find($id)->permissions
```

This will give me the collection of ProductPermission objects as expected. One of the attributes of the ProductPermission model is 'permission' which is the text string. For example "users*".

I want to be able to do something similar to this

```
\App\Product::find(3)->permissions->search($permission) //$permission = "users*"
```

But this returns false despite a ProductPermission object with the attribute `permission=users*` existing. How can I search the attributes (or the specific attribute) of all the objects in the relationship collection?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

This works...

```
\App\Product::find($id)->permissions->where('permission',$permission)->count();
```

But its not as pretty

Answer (score 0):

You may use `whereHas` like follows:

```php
$productsWithPermissionsCount = Product::whereHas('permissions', function ($query) {
    $query->where('permission', '=', $permission);
})->count();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I am not sure how that adds anything.. except a bit of complexity